# How to parse the data present in the logs which doesn't have any separator?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to do some analysis based on the logs I received from someone.
Analyzing each log individually is very time consuming, so thought to write a script using python and pandas to do this automatically.
But the data is mixed and hence I am not able to parse it.

The logs are as follow:

```
14:34:41: [REQ][LS1]->[TUT2] [12]FF00000000000000000088DD (Message1)
14:34:41: [REQ][TUT2]->[LS1] [09]5203000C0C0C0C0E0E (Message2)
14:34:49: [REQ][LS1]->[TUT2] [12]FF00000000000000000088DD (Message1)
14:34:49: [REQ][TUT2]->[LS1] [09]5203000C0C0C0C0E0E (Message2)
14:34:56: [REQ][LS1]->[TUT2] [12]FF00000000000000000088DD (Message1)
14:34:57: [REQ][TUT2]->[LS1] [09]5203000C0C0C0C0E0E (Message2)
14:35:04: [REQ][LS1]->[TUT2] [12]FF00000000000000000088DD (Message1)
14:35:05: [REQ][TUT2]->[LS1] [09]5203000C0C0C0C0E0E (Message2)
14:35:05: [REQ][TUT2]->[000] [25]DB03FFFFFF7F00000000FF7F0000FF7F00FA0FF90F00000000 (Debug Message)
```

and I need the output as this.

```
FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 88 DD
52 03 00 0C 0C 0C 0C 0E 0E
FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 88 DD
52 03 00 0C 0C 0C 0C 0E 0E
FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 88 DD
52 03 00 0C 0C 0C 0C 0E 0E
FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 88 DD
52 03 00 0C 0C 0C 0C 0E 0E
DB 03 FF FF FF 7F 00 00 00 00 FF 7F 00 00 FF 7F 00 FA 0F F9 0F 00 00 00 00
```

So that I can analyse the data.

I used the following code, to parse the data.

```
import pandas as pd
# Read File
filename = "file.txt"
df = pd.read_table(filename, sep=' ',\
                   names=['Time','Src-Dst','Data','Type','Remarks'],\
                   engine='python',header=None)
df.head()
```

But I don't understand how to parse this data into separate columns.

```
[12]2A00000000000000000088DD
```

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.Series.str.findall`:

```
df['Data'].str[4:].str.findall('(.{2})')
```

Output:

```
0     [FF, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 88, DD]
1                 [52, 03, 00, 0C, 0C, 0C, 0C, 0E, 0E]
2     [FF, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 88, DD]
3                 [52, 03, 00, 0C, 0C, 0C, 0C, 0E, 0E]
4     [FF, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 88, DD]
5                 [52, 03, 00, 0C, 0C, 0C, 0C, 0E, 0E]
6     [FF, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 88, DD]
7                 [52, 03, 00, 0C, 0C, 0C, 0C, 0E, 0E]
8    [DB, 03, FF, FF, FF, 7F, 00, 00, 00, 00, FF, 7...
Name: Data, dtype: object
```

If you want this to be a dataframe, make new one:

```
s = df['Data'].str[4:].str.findall('(.{2})')
pd.DataFrame(list(s))
```

Output:

```
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8     9   ...     15    16    17    18  \
0  FF  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00    00  ...   None  None  None  None   
1  52  03  00  0C  0C  0C  0C  0E  0E  None  ...   None  None  None  None   
2  FF  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00    00  ...   None  None  None  None   
3  52  03  00  0C  0C  0C  0C  0E  0E  None  ...   None  None  None  None   
4  FF  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00    00  ...   None  None  None  None   
5  52  03  00  0C  0C  0C  0C  0E  0E  None  ...   None  None  None  None   
6  FF  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00    00  ...   None  None  None  None   
7  52  03  00  0C  0C  0C  0C  0E  0E  None  ...   None  None  None  None   
8  DB  03  FF  FF  FF  7F  00  00  00    00  ...     7F    00    FA    0F   

     19    20    21    22    23    24  
0  None  None  None  None  None  None  
1  None  None  None  None  None  None  
2  None  None  None  None  None  None  
3  None  None  None  None  None  None  
4  None  None  None  None  None  None  
5  None  None  None  None  None  None  
6  None  None  None  None  None  None  
7  None  None  None  None  None  None  
8    F9    0F    00    00    00    00
```